# Как вывести числовой массив в текстовое поле на форме

Tags: c++

Имеется форма, на форме 4 поля "edit":

- в первое поле пользователь вводит число(количество элементов в массиве),
- в следующий "edit" число `a`,
- в следующий число `c`
- и в последний число `x`.

Затем массив заполняется:

```
    char str1[MAX_PATH];
    char str2[MAX_PATH];
    char str3[MAX_PATH];
    char str4[MAX_PATH];
    char* res = new char[];

    int kol;
    int a;
    int c;
    int x;

    kol = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, 500, NULL, false);
    int* mass = new int[];
    mass[0] = 1;
    a = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, 4, NULL, false);
    c = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, 6, NULL, false);
    x = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, 8, NULL, false);
    mass[0] = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++){
        mass[i+1] = (a*mass[i]+c)%kol;
    }
```

Еще на форме имеется текстовое поле "static", которое создается вот так:

```
CreateWindow(  TEXT("static")
             , TEXT("")
             ,   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT 
               | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_BORDER
             , 0, 120, 400, 20
             , hWnd
             , HMENU(3)
             , hInstance
             , 0          );
```

В это поле необходимо вывести в одну строчку числа массива. К это сделать?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под полем "static"?

Comment: думаю подобие lable из того же с#, у меня создается так: CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_BORDER, 0, 120, 400, 20, hWnd, HMENU(3), hInstance, 0);

Comment: Это в вопрос надо писать

Comment: Добавил, знаю как выводить текст в данное поле: SetDlgItemText(hwnd, 3, "строка"), но как вывести массив чисел понять не могу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iterator>

 ...

 std::strstream text;
 std::copy(  mas
           , mas + kol
           , std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(text, " "));
 SetDlgItemText(hwnd, 3, text.c_str());
```

Comment: Почти) в моем случае правильно будет так: stringstream sstr; for (int i = 0; i<kol; i++)
     sstr1 << mass[i] << ", ";

    SetDlgItemText(hwnd, 200, sstr1.str().c_str());